# How to assert an attribute within another method

Tags: python, decorator, patch, assert

EDIT* It seems I was misleading people with some unintentional words. I had thought all functions when instanaited to methods contained attributes. But I really just wanted to test the variable in the function from class2.

I'm very new to python & unittesting, so please forgive me if what I am asking is completely delusional.

I wanted to know if it is "possible to assert a variable within another function from the outter scope". I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot modify Class2.py
```

**Class1.py**

```
from Class2.py import Class2
Class1(unittest.TestCase)
    def test_class2_fun(self):
        driver = Class2()
        driver.class2_fun

        assertTrue(driver.class2_fun.class2_variable) "???
```

**Class2.py**

```
Class2(self)
    def class2_fun(self):
        class2_variable = TRUE
```

Not sure how to go about it with the proper syntax.  Is it possible through either a decorator before I assign driver with `Class2()` or through a patch somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to test `Class1` functionality whilst you are testing `Class2`? If the `Class1` is problematic then you should consider mocking it using `unittest.mock`.

Comment: `class2_attribute` isn't a class attribute. It's not an attribute of anything; it's a local variable. A separate `class2_attribute` is created for each run of `class2_fun`, and when the function isn't running, the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: the above is true.  i assumed you meant an actual attribute and just had a typo.  if by `class2_attribute` you mean what your code says, i.e. that it's a local variable, you wont be able to check for it outside the function its defined in.

Comment: I was trying to assert for the "variable"! So what I was trying to test is not possible? even with a patch decorator- with some assert side_effect, if possible?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that what you want to do is not really possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few typos in your class and function definitions but you want to use the [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) function will tell you if an object has a specific attribute.

If what you want to do is check for the existence of `local variable` outside the function `__init__` of class `Class2`, I don't think that is possible without modifying the contents of the file `Class2.py`.

### Working Example

**In Class1.py**

```
import unittest
from Class2 import Class2

class Class1(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_class2_at_exists(self):
        driver = Class2()
        self.assertTrue( hasattr( driver, 'class2_attribute' ) )

    def test_class2_at_value(self):
        driver = Class2()
        self.assertTrue( driver.class2_attribute == 'attribute value' )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**In Class2.py**

```
class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.class2_attribute = 'attribute value'
        local_variable = True
```

**At an ipython prompt**,

```
>>> run Class1.py
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to assert the 'value' for the attribute itself. I just assume there has to be some way of checking it as the method is running

Comment: check out this [basic example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example). I'll update my answer with the proper syntax, but you should read up on classes, functions, and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your assert should instead be

```
   assertTrue(driver.class2_attribute)
```